# Unable to Render data using API on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When a button is clicked, the API data cannot be rendered. It generates the two errors listed below. Please advise me on how to resolve this.

**Error Details:**

1. ./src/router/AppRouter.js
   Attempted import error: 'Feedback' is not exported from '../components/Feedback'.
2. ./src/components/Customerfeedbacks.js
   SyntaxError: \src\components\Customerfeedbacks.js: Missing semicolon. (9:27)
   Failed to compile.

**Feedback.js**

```
import React from 'react';

class Feedback extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            employees: []
        };
        componentDidMount() {
            Fetch("http://localhost:3002/posts").then(res => res.json()).then(
                (result) => {
                    this.setState({
                        employees: result
                    });
                }
            );

        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Employees Data...</h2>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Location</th>
                            <th>Salary</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {this.state.employees.map(emp => (
                            <tr key={emp.Id}>
                                <td>{emp.Id}</td>
                                <td>{emp.Name}</td>
                                <td>{emp.Location}</td>
                                <td>{emp.Salary}</td>
                            </tr>
                        ))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
const element=<EmployeeComponent></EmployeeComponent>

ReactDOM.render(element,document.getElementById("root"));

export default Feedback;
```

AppRouter.JS

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from '../components/Header';
import AddEvent from '../components/AddEvent';
import EventsList from '../components/EventsList';
import useLocalStorage from '../hooks/useLocalStorage.js';
import EditEvent from '../components/EditEvent';
import EventsContext from '../context/EventsContext';
import { About } from '../components/About';
import { Home } from '../components/Home';
import { Feedback } from '../components/Feedback';

const AppRouter = () => {
  const [books, setBooks] = useLocalStorage('books', []);

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Header />
        <div className="main-content">
          <EventsContext.Provider value={{ books, setBooks }}>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/about" component={About} exact />
              <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
              <Route component={EventsList} path="/eventList" exact={true} />
              <Route component={AddEvent} path="/add" />
              <Route component={EditEvent} path="/edit/:id" />
              <Route component={Feedback} path="/feedback"/>
              <Route component={() => <Redirect to="/" />} />
            </Switch>
          </EventsContext.Provider>
        </div>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default AppRouter;
```

Comment: the errors are pretty much self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

You are importing `Feedback` which is exported as default so its import will be

`import Feedback from '../components/Feedback';`

For your second error, You are adding a semi colon after your `then` statement so just copy paste this. Also read the errors thoroughly and try to understand what they are telling you

```
componentDidMount() {
fetch("http://localhost:3002/posts")
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((result) => {
    this.setState({
      employees: result,
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're importing `Feedback` as if it's a named import, but your export statement is:

```
export default Feedback;
```

So your import statement should be:

```
import Feedback from '../components/Feedback';
```

(You didn't show the other source file, but the error looks fairly self-explanatory)

Comment: ./src/components/Feedback.js
SyntaxError: \src\components\Feedback.js: Missing semicolon. (9:27)

   7 |             employees: []
   8 |         };
>  9 |         componentDidMount() {
     |                            ^
  10 |             Fetch("http://localhost:3002/posts").then(res => res.json()).then(
  11 |                 (result) => {
  12 |                     this.setState({

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issue observed in your code

**Improvement needed.**

1- use **fetch** not **Fetch** to make API call

```
componentDidMount() {
   fetch("http://localhost:3002/posts")
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(result => this.setState({employees: result}));
 }
```

2- Remove `ReactDOM.render(element,document.getElementById("root"));` from Feedback component and just export.

3- Since you have used default export, import like this

```
import Feedback from '../components/Feedback';
```

Answer (score 0):

Default exported components should be imported with no brackets.

```
import Feedback from '../components/Feedback'
```

and please share the customerFeedback.js file.

Comment: I changed the name.. It is feedback.js.. Added in the description

Comment: I see. On the feedback.js, you should avoid placing the componentDidMount function inner the constructor function.
Also please remove the ReactDom.render().

Answer (score 0):

In your AppRouter.JS, as you are using `import { Feedback } from '../components/Feedback';`

So your export statement in components/Feedback should be :

```js
export Feedback;
```

There are some other bugs also so This code will solve all your major problems :

```js
import React from 'react';

class Feedback extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            employees: []
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("http://localhost:3002/posts").then(res => res.json()).then(
            (result) => {
                this.setState({
                    employees: result
                });
            }
        );
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Employees Data...</h2>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Location</th>
                            <th>Salary</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {this.state.employees.map(emp => (
                            <tr key={emp.Id}>
                                <td>{emp.Id}</td>
                                <td>{emp.Name}</td>
                                <td>{emp.Location}</td>
                                <td>{emp.Salary}</td>
                            </tr>
                        ))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export Feedback
```

Comment: I did all changes still getting below error


\src\components\Feedback.js: Missing semicolon. (10:27)

   8 |             employees: []
   9 |         };
> 10 |         componentDidMount() {
     |                            ^
  11 |             fetch("http://localhost:3002/posts")
  12 |               .then((res) => res.json())
  13 |               .then((result) => {

Comment: Latest Code
`
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Feedback extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            employees: []
        };
        componentDidMount() {
            fetch("http://localhost:3002/posts")
              .then((res) => res.json())
              .then((result) => {
                this.setState({
                  employees: result,
                });
              });
            }
    }
    render() {
        return (
`

Comment: I have made the necessary changes